# How to find DataGridView of one form in another form?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Ok i am totally new to WinForms ,  I am trying to find DataGridView1 WHich I have on one form(frmPledgeCreation) on another form by

`frmPledgeCreation.Controls.Find("DataGridView1", True)`

The problem is that when i check the row count of the DataGridView1 on the second form... i always get 1  even when there are numerous rows in the DataGridView1 on frmPledgeCreation.

Is `frmPledgeCreation.Controls.Find("DataGridView1", True)` creating a new instance? 
My aim is to set the value of cell of a particular column of this DataGridView from this other form  something like this...

`DGV.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(gDGVindex)).Cells("SecurityName").Value = GstrSearchResult.ToString()`

where `gDGVindex` is a global variable which has the rowindex .. but i always get outofrange error.

Comment: Make that DataGridView1 public and use on other form. For further data you can refer datasource binded to the datagrid view

Comment: please post your actual code. This is so confusing to say anything. BTW the `ControlCollection.Find` method is not what you want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing the same thing. I would expose a public function in your form. This function would take care of updating the grid.

frmPledgeCreation.UpdateSomeCell(GstrSearchResult.ToString())

You must already have a DataGridView1 property.

An other way would be to change the DataGridView1 from private/protected to public.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference of frmPledgeCreation in the form where you want to access the DataGridView1

in frmPledgeCreation

```
class frmPledgeCreation:Form
{
 public DataGridView dgv{get{return DataGridView1;}}
 Form1()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 }
}
```

for display Form2

```
Form2 f=new Form2(this);
f.show();
```

in Form2

```
class Form2
{
 frmPledgeCreation reftof1;
 Form2(frmPledgeCreation f)
 {
  reftof1=f;
 }
}
```

now you can access the DataGridView in Form2 using the reftof1 reference

```
reftof1.dgv.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(gDGVindex)].Cells["SecurityName"].Value=GstrSearchResult.ToString()
```

Comment: @Arbaaz whats the error? Are you still getting OutOfRange exception?

Comment: @Arbaaz at which line? Is your DGV data-bound?

Answer (score 0):

you could create public function that would update the grid and than you could call that function
[here is an answer to similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04746346-2be1-4ef3-8d54-102077f3ecca/c-winforms-how-to-access-parentform-from-childform?forum=csharplanguage)

parent form

```
   Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.Show(this);
```

child form

```
((Form1)Owner).DoSomething();
```

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.